# Print nested associative array keys as row numbers

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I have a nested associative array that prints out users data in a table. Here is the code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
            <th>Nume de familie</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Oras</th>
            <th>Adresa</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($user_data as $arr){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        row number nedded here
                    </td>                           
                    <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value){ ?>
                    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to display the row number instead at the most left, instead of "row number nedded here"

Comment: what does mean *number instead at the most left* ?

Comment: Your second/inner array iteration shows what you need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a variable as a counter and display that:

```
<tbody>
    <?php $counter=0; foreach ($user_data as $arr){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo ++$counter; ?>
            </td>                           
            <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value){ ?>
                <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, if you have not any key you have index number starting from 0.

```
 <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($user_data as $key=>$arr){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $key+1 ;?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $arr["prenume"];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $arr["nume"];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $arr["email"];?>
                </td>
                ...............

        </tr>
    <?php }?>
   </tbody>
```